# Android (Java): Parse.com not subscribing to channel that isn't a hard-coded string?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, channel, hardcoded

When I subscribe to few channels on the parse.com service, it works perfectly, like this:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.addAllUnique("channels", Arrays.asList("CHANNEL_1", "CHANNEL_2", "CHANNEL_3", "CHANNEL_4"));
installation.saveInBackground();
```

But, when I don't hard-code the strings, it doesn't work?

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
String spinnerValue= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
installation.addAllUnique("channels", Arrays.asList(spinnerValue, "CHANNEL_2", "CHANNEL_3", "CHANNEL_4"));
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Do I have to hardcode all the channels when working with Parse.com?

Comment: What is the value of `spinnerValue`?

Comment: It evaluates a string -> "8" or "pizza" etc.

Comment: OK, how do you check that the subscription was unsuccessful? Also, can you confirm that "8" is a valid channel name for the service you're using?

Comment: Let me have a look, that may be the problem...

Comment: So sorry, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value of `spinnerValue` ("8") is not a valid channel name. Thus, the subscription doesn't work.